# how to count only if light sensor event going from 100 to 50 and don't count if it from 0 to 50

Tags: java, android, light-sensor

How to count only if light sensor event going from 100 to 50  and don't count if it from 0 to 50 ?

I'm using light sensor in my app( onsensorchange event ) 
I want to count only if light fade from 100 to 50% then add +1 to my counter

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sen = //get value of event.values[0] 
    }
});

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
        if (sen => half of event.values[0]) {
            // add +1 to my counter
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is they count when  event.values[0] goes  from 100 to 50 and from 0 to 50

Comment: Will counter is increased when sensor value goes from 50 to 100 ?

Comment: From High to Low  

when light value  decreased only  add +1

for example 50% of event.value[0]